# install $prefix/bin/ghc-X.Y.Z, but not overwrite $prefix/bin/ghc

Tags: haskell, ghc

I want to install a fresh ghc version (a RC, say), but not overwrite the previous one. (So it should be available as `ghc-X.Y.Z`, but not as `ghc`)

I think the only place where overwriting actually happens, is the symlinks for executables. How can I avoid this? (some magic option for `make install`?)

I know as a work-around I can keep the previous build and re-install.

Comment: You could install the new ghc into a different $prefix. You would have to add $newprefix/bin to your PATH, but otherwise you wouldn't have to worry about overwriting anything.